# How to add Identity Services in ASP.NET Core 5

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-5

I'm trying to add Identity Services.

And I'm trying to change the number of columns in the user table. I don't know how to correct it.

- Version - .NET 5
- Identity nuget version - 5.0.1

When I change

```
// IT DOESN'T WORK
services.AddIdentityCore<User>() 
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationContext>();
```

to

```
 // this works
services.AddIdentityCore<IdentityUser>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationContext>();
```

Code:

```
// Startup.cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    
    services.AddIdentityCore<User>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationContext>();
    
    services.AddRazorPages();
}
    
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public int Year { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: So,What's the error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to change like below:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<User>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Be sure your DbContext like below:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

Be sure update `_LoginPartial.cshtml` and replace `IdentityUser` with `User`:

```
@inject SignInManager<User> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<User> UserManager
```

Finally,you could scarffold the Identity.